# Try/Catch Example

Tags: powershell

I understand Stackoverflow isn't a *write your code for you* forum, absolutely, but I'm finding it very difficult to find a good example of `try/catch` proper usage in Powershell. I have read up on fundamentals, and understand the theoretical concept, but execution I'm struggling with.

Here is a simple script that queries Active Directory:

```
do {
    clear
    Import-Module active*

    "============ WhoIs Lookup ============="
    Write-Host ""
    $who = Read-Host "WhoIs";


    $req = Get-ADUser -Identity $who 


    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host "$who is " -NoNewline
    Write-Host $req.Name -ForegroundColor Cyan
    pause
    } while ($run =1)
```

An example error is:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with
identity: '5621521' under: 'DC=dcsg,DC=com'.
At C:\Tools\CSOCTools\Who_Is\whoIs.ps1:10
char:12
+     $req = Get-ADUser -Identity $who
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFoun
   d: (5621521:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIde
  ntityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirecto
   ryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Mana
  gement.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Micr
 osoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Comman
ds.GetADUser
```

How would I `catch` this *User Not Found* error?

Comment: There are many examples available on the web. Does this one help? https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-04-10-Powershell-exceptions-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know/

Comment: Kevin's writing style often gets lost on me, honestly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example:

```
try {
  Get-ADUser -Identity “bleh”
}
catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException]
{
  Write-Warning “AD computer object not found”
}
```

For your case:

```
do {
  clear
  Import-Module active*

  "============ WhoIs Lookup ============="
  Write-Host ""
  $who = Read-Host "WhoIs";

  try {
    $req = Get-ADUser -Identity $who 
  } 
  catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException]
  {
    Write-Warning “AD user object not found”
    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host "$who is " -NoNewline
    Write-Host $req.Name -ForegroundColor Cyan
  }
  pause
} while ($run =1)
```

Edit: I put the Write-Host into the catch as you're eventually trying to reference to `NULL` when there's no object.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. This clears up every misconception I had and again it appears I was just over-complicating it.

Comment: I also forgot that Powershell gives me the name of cmdlets I can listen for which is a huge oversight.

Answer (score 1):

I got a very good example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6). For the exception types after the `Catch` (where I have two of them) I just grabbed them straight from the error message you provided. I haven't tried this out many times in my experience, let me know if it works for ya!

```
Try 
{
    do {
        clear
        Import-Module active*

        "============ WhoIs Lookup ============="
        Write-Host ""
        $who = Read-Host "WhoIs";


        $req = Get-ADUser -Identity $who 


        Write-Host ''
        Write-Host "$who is " -NoNewline
        Write-Host $req.Name -ForegroundColor Cyan
        pause
    } while ($run =1)
}
Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException],[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser]
{
     # Error message here
}
```